# String cannot be cast to Float - Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
val nextDigit = passedList[i + 1] as Float
```

I'm trying cast this and It's giving that error. I tried with .toFloat() but It doesn't work..

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
    at com.example.calculator.MainActivity.calcTimesDiv(MainActivity.kt:108)
```

Comment: Why don't you used .toFloat() extension function of String in Kotlin?
Please check this reference.
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-float.html

Comment: Post your code if you're still having a problem, because calling `toFloat()` on a `String` should always work (the parsing itself might fail, but the call will work). Casting is about treating an object as one of its *types* (a superclass or one of the interfaces it implements) and a `String` is *not* a `Float` so you can't treat it as one in Kotlin or Java. There's no automatic conversion going on like in some languages

Answer (score 3):

`as` is a type casting operator. String and Float cannot be cast to each other. It is as simple as that. You will need to use extension functions like "toFloat()" that read the content of string and try to interpret is as a float value.

Comment: When I wrote "toFloat()", I'm getting this "Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline fun String.toFloat(): Float defined in kotlin.text"

Comment: You write it as `"1".toFloat()`. Remember though, that this can throw a `NumberFormatException`that needs to be caught. If `toFloat()` is not available you need to check your project setup.

Comment: How can I check project setup? Where should I look?

Comment: Kotlin version would be the first thing to take a look at

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
val nextDigit = passedList[i + 1]
nextDigit.toFloat()
```

Comment: It says "Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline fun String.toFloat(): Float defined in kotlin.text"

Comment: What is return type of passedList[i+1] ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
val nextDigit = (passedList[i + 1]).toFloat()
```

PS: It is always good practice to wrap type cast inside `try` and `catch` block because Type casting may cause exception.

Comment: It says same "Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: public inline fun String.toFloat(): Float defined in kotlin.text"